# Is there a way to run Raspberry Pi Image on Windows?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, image, emulation, virtualization

I have a Raspberry Pi with [Raspbian Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) OS installed, I want to take an image of its current state then run in it in virtual environment on my `Windows` machine, make some changes to the OS state (i.e. install some software, add some files, etc.) take a new image and then run this new image on Raspberry Pi. 
I found a virtual machine for Raspberry `VirtualBox` but it does not work with `Raspbian` OS so I cannot create an image that will be compatible with an actual Raspberry Pi.

Are there any good, relatively easy solutions to this problem?

Comment: related https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32171/19949 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/45670/19949

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi has an ARM processor which is incompatible to the x86 processor family of your MS-Windows PC. That's why VirtualBox et al. do nothing.

You have to emulate the ARM processor in software. QEMU can do this, but it's rather slow. See e.g. [here.](https://www.qemu.org/)